# How to sort the query result by the value in one column, depending on the value in the second column using CriteriaBuilder

Tags: hibernate, predicate, specifications, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

The query is built using Predicate and the Specification implementation and the result is the returned Page<>, and the example shown is a simplification of the entire database structure sufficient to represent the problem.

The data is returned based on two tables `Car` and `Element`.
The filtered value is based on the data in table `Car`, which is linked to table `Elements` with a one-to-many relationship.
The result should be sorted based on the values in table `Element`, but only for rows where the `manufacturer` column has the indicated value.

How to sort by `Element_.value` only if `Element_.manufacturer = 5`, and for the `!= 5` condition, e.g. comparing the value as `null` or leaving it unsorted.

```
@Getter
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "f_car")
public class Car {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private List<Element> elements;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "f_element")
public class Element {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "car_id")
    private Long carId;

    private Long manufacturer;

    private String value;
}
```

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SpecForView implements Specification<Car> {

    private final String name;
    private final Long manufacturerId;

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Car> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        Predicate namePredicate = cb.equal(root.get(Car_.name), name);

       // TODO: a place in the code to set the sort
}
```

Sample values in the database
[image]

Answer (score 1):

By using a case when statement:

```
Join<Car, Element> e = root.join(Car_.elements);
cq.orderBy(
  cb.selectCase()
    .when(
      cb.equal(e.get(Element_.manufacturer), manufacturerId), 
      e.get(Element_.value)
    ).otherwise(cb.nullLiteral(String.class))
);
```

Comment: It works! However, there was a new problem with this solution as the returned values are duplicated. For example, two CAR entries were returned without sorting, and after an additional sort, 4 entries are returned (each of the two CAR has two ELEMENT entries).

Comment: Well, that's what you get when you join a collection. You can use `cq.distinct()` to remove duplicates.

Comment: I tried calling cq.distinct (true), but an exception is thrown: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

Comment: You need to pass a hint to Hibernate to disable passing through the distinct to SQL. Set `hibernate.query.passDistinctThrough` to `false`

Comment: When this value is changed to false, no exception is thrown, but the behavior is the same as before adding cq.distinct (true) and setting false for org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, so duplicates are still returned.

Comment: You can filter out the duplicates by wrapping it in a `LinkedHashSet`, but if you still receive duplicates, I would say this is a bug and you should report this in the Hibernate issue tracker (https://hibernate.atlassian.net) and attach a test case (https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: If I start manually filtering duplicates from the query result from the database, I will lose the page paging mechanism.

Comment: Oh you are paging this? In that case you are out of luck anyway because the collection join destroys the cardinality for paging. If you want a drop-in replacement for the paging that also supports collections, I recommend that you use the Blaze-Persistence Spring Data JPA integration: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/#spring-data-integration